# Searching for a software for fast jump between windows

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

For example:

```
Win+C - go to the last command line window
Win+SHIFT+C Open new command line
Win+W - Go to microsoft word
Win+Shift+W - open new microsoft word windows
Hold(WIN)+W+W+W - move between microsoft word windows.
```

I want to set a shourtcut for each button.

I know I can move using WIN[1..9] the problem is that when pressing for example WIN+2 it moves to the first opened window, but I want to go back to the last opened window I used.

Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to improve it. Take a look other question as well: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/22984/software-for-fast-switching-only-keyboard-to-specific-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I decide to do it by Myself by using Auto-HotKeys.
The is the APK file.
It's working in the example for Chrome, Notepad and sublime.

https://github.com/AminaG/AutoHotKeys-TaskSwitch/blob/master/appshortcuts.ahk

If you have an idea how to improve it,please contribute to the source code.
I need help with make it work for any software by configuration file (instead of change the APK for each software)

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

;********command line
#c::
IfWinExist ,cmd.exe
{
ifWinActive
WinActivatebottom ,cmd.exe
else
WinActivate
return
}
#+c::
run cmd.exe /k cd\
return
#^+c::
loop 5 
winClose cmd.exe
return

;******************Chrome
#h::
IfWinExist ,Chrome
    {
    ifWinActive
        {
        WinActivatebottom ,Chrome
    }
    else
    {
        WinActivate
    }
    return
}

#+h::
run "chrome"
return
#^+h::
loop 5 
winClose Chrome
return

;**********Sublime Text
#s::
IfWinExist ,Sublime
    {
    ifWinActive
        {
        WinActivatebottom ,Sublime
    }
    else
    {
        WinActivate
    }
    return
}
#+s::
run "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe" -n
return
#^+s::
loop 5
winClose Sublime
return

;**************Notepad
#n::
IfWinExist ,Notepad
    {
    ifWinActive
        {
        WinActivatebottom ,Notepad
    }
    else
    {
        WinActivate
    }
    return
}

#+n::
run "notepad"
return
#^+n::
loop 5
winClose Notepad
return


;**********Explorer
#Space::
IfWinExist ,ahk_class CabinetWClass
    {

    ifWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass
        {
        WinActivatebottom ,ahk_class CabinetWClass
    }
    else
    {
        WinActivate
    }
    return
}

#+Space::
run "Explorer" d:\
return
#^+Space::
loop 5 
winClose ahk_class CabinetWClass
return


#Enter::
sendevent {LButton down}
keywait #
sendevent {LButton up}
return

#AppsKey::
sendevent {RButton down}
keywait #
sendevent {RButton up}
return
```

Comment: For other readers:  **Win+C** is useful built-in Windows shortcut since Windows 8. Try to use some unoccupied shortcut instead. I suggest **AppsKey+(letter)**. AppsKey space can be entirely yours. If you don't have that key, you can consider for example CapsLock, so shortcuts will be CapsLock+(letter).

Answer (score 1):

This can probably be done with AutoHotKey (http://ahkscript.org/)

You can configure it to fulfill your requirements, have a look at the [WinActivate](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm)-function for instance.

Comment: I  can do everything wieh Auto-HoKeys. I am searching for something that ready. I found one in the past, but I don't find it any more. It's called "HotKeys"