# Software for fast switching (only keyboard) to specific window

Tags: windows, productivity, window-manager

I am searching for a software for fast searching between windows for Microsoft Windows.

- I want to be able to see the titles, and decide the window I want to open by title.
- I want to be able to start type the window title, for fast switcihng.
- Everything only by using the keyboard, and focus on switching to specific window by title

Do you know about anything?

If I will not found anything, I will develop it. You can ask this by upvote (I am joking)

I found something similar for Mac: https://contexts.co/ (Attached a screenshot)

[image: Contexts.co App (C)]
[[image: UI for demonstration][2](https://i.snag.gy/E1DWb.jpg)

Other UI I created, for what I search. for demonstration

Comment: You might consider upgrading to Windows 10 (if you haven't already). It has a new Task View that allows you to create virtual desktops and organize your windows. However, I don't think you can search for a window by name.

Comment: The 7+ Taskbar Tweaker utility has a feature called Taskbar Inspector which is a little bit like what you are describing (it gives you a list of everything in the taskbar, which you can then rearrange or navigate to using the mouse). I assume this is still not close enough to what you want, but there is also the 7+ Taskbar Tweaking Library, which might be useful for when you try to program it yourself.

Comment: I am searching for something that I can use only the keyboard. I will check for 7+ taskbar tweaking library

Comment: Not what you ask, but a way to quickly switch (especially if you have pins in your taskbar and only one instance of each program): Win+number (1-9): Starts the application pinned to the taskbar in that position, or switches to that program.

Comment: I upvoted. Please post a link to your GitHub project ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [Switcher](http://insentient.net/)? It’s free, a portable version is available and in the options under “Window Style” you can set the label to “{title}” so it shows the window title. Beginning to type puts you into search mode or you can use numbers to switch windows.
I’ve not yet tested it on Windows 8 and higher, but on Windows 7 it works like a charm.

Comment: Wow. Wow Wow!!!!
A must use software!!!
How did you find it?
I am sorry that the last version is 2007. But it is still works like new one!

Comment: @Amina I think I found it on Lifehacker a while ago after quite a while of searching for something like this as well :).

Answer (score 1):

Learn Autohotkey. With just a bit of programming learning, you can have any hotkey do anything, the least of which switch to a window.

I have been using it for years now and have a program with close to hundred of commands and hotkeys and functions amassed that facilitate my workspace and space me uncountable keyboard presses and mouse clicks and of course facilitate my workspace.

It works on any Windows platform including Windows 10 and will make this "Switcher" feel like childplay after a few weeks of getting into it.